Range Hood over Kitchen Island installation
We have a kitchen island and we would like to install a range hood over it. This is a two story house. The ceiling over the kitchen does not open into the attic.
Is it possible to do a hood installation?


Go out though the wall.  You will have joists above the ceiling going in one direction.  An elbow and duct should fit in between two joists with a straight run out to the wall.

"The ceiling over the kitchen does not open into the attic"; what exactly is above that ceiling?

"Is it possible?" isn't a question that's helpful to you or this community, as the answer is always "sure, for enough money". Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask something more specific, providing enough detail for us to answer.

Looks like you might be fighting for space in the ceiling with the existing duct-work, but either you rearrange the ductwork in the ceiling to put it in the ceiling, or you put the duct under the ceiling and run to the nearest (preferably) outside wall, or whatever outside wall you want to use.
Alternatively you use one of the systems that pulls stove fumes down through the cabinet into the basement, and to an outside wall that way. Those typically mount behind the stove, and "pop up" when needed, other than the Jenn-Air version (I can't recall any others doing it that way) that's built into the top of the stove. I do recall their version as being quite noisy, since air velocity needs to be high to take fumes a direction they don't naturally want to go.
It will be a major project, but it's also a glaring defect in the way the kitchen was designed, so solving it is for the best if you actually cook, (apparently unlike the kitchen designer.)
